Asymptotic behavior of partial sums of Dirichlet series
Consider the Dirichlet series:
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s+1/3)}{\zeta(s)}$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.
Question: Assuming the Riemann Hypothesis (RH), how can we prove that:
$$\sum_{n \leq x} a_n \sim \frac{x^{2/3}}{(2/3)\zeta(2/3)} \quad \text{as } x \to \infty$$
Since $a_n = \sum_{d|n} d^{-1/3} \mu(n/d) = O(n^\varepsilon)$ I considered using Perron's formula on the rectangle
$$[\delta-iT, \delta+iT, 2/3+\varepsilon+iT, 2/3+\varepsilon-iT]$$
where $1/2<\delta<2/3$. However, I'm unsure how to effectively estimate $\frac{\zeta(s+1/3)}{\zeta(s)}$.
The Lindelöf hypothesis doesn't seem to provide sufficient information for the estimation, possibly due to the denominator in the Dirichlet series.
Edit: factor added in the asymptotic formula thanks to the answer.

The correct asymptotics are $\frac{3}{2}$ times $x^{2/3}/\zeta(2/3)$ (you are missing a factor of $3/2$). A proof under RH:
Fix $\delta \in (0,\tfrac{1}{6})$. Apply Perron's effective formula to your Dirichlet series, with the parameters $T=x^{\tfrac{1}{3}+\delta}$ and line of integration $\Re s = 1+\frac{1}{\log x}$. Next, apply Cauchy's Residue Theorem to the rectangle $$\left[\frac{2}{3}-\delta-iT, \frac{2}{3}-\delta+iT, 1+\frac{1}{\log x}+iT, 1+\frac{1}{\log x}-iT\right].$$
The integrand $\frac{\zeta(s+1/3)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^s}{s}$ has only one singularity in the rectangle, by RH, at $s= 2/3$, which contributes the residue $\frac{3}{2}\frac{x^{2/3}}{\zeta(2/3)}$. It remains to bound the integral of $\frac{\zeta(s+1/3)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^s}{s}$ over 3 edges of the rectangle: $s=\frac{2}{3}-\delta+it$ with $t\in [-T,T]$, and $s=\sigma\pm iT$ with $\sigma \in \left[ \frac{2}{3}-\delta,1+\frac{1}{\log x}\right]$.
To bound the numerator $\zeta(s+1/3)$ use $\zeta(\sigma+it)\ll (|t|+4)^{o(1)}$ for $|t| \ge 1$ and $\sigma \ge \frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$ (Lindelöf). To bound the denominator $\zeta(s)$ you can use $1/\zeta(\sigma+it)\ll (|t|+4)^{o(1)}$ for $|t| \ge 1$ and $\sigma \ge \frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$ (Theorem 13.23 in Montgomery and Vaughan). $\blacksquare$
It is true that the Lindelöf hypothesis is not enough (because $\zeta(s)$ is in the denominator, not the numerator), but actually the Riemann Hypothesis is somewhat of an overkill - you only need a quasi-Riemann Hypothesis (a sufficiently wide zero-free strip). At the very least, one needs to assume $\zeta(s) \neq 0$ for $\Re s \ge \frac{2}{3}$.

Thank you for this detailed response.
A follow-up question: Is there an equivalent of Theorem 13.23 from Montgomery and Vaughan for $L(\chi,s)$, where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character?

@Babar Under GRH it should be true for other L-functions, but I don't have a reference.

Thank you, this seems consistent with the generalization for Lindelöf...
